# how to use IAM policy variables in terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

```
{
  "Sid": "Allow bucket write",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": [
      "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
    ]
  },
  "Action": "s3:PutObject",
  "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.log-dev-test-bucket-test.arn}/AWSLogs/${var.organization_id}/${aws:PrincipalAccount}/*",
  "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"}}
},
```

I am getting this message on my Resource section with regard to ${aws:PrincipalAccount}:

"Extra characters after interpolation expression: Template interpolation doesn't expect a colon at this location. Did you intend this to be a literal sequence to be processed as part of another language? If so, you can escape it by starting with "$${" instead of just "${".HCL"

The error message is suggesting to use $${aws:PrincipalAccount} to escape it.I don't know what that will do to it because i need to have this IAM policy variable in the policy statement resource section to achieve my goal.can any explain what escape will do if i use $$ instead of $ before {aws:PrincipalAccount}.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no such IAM variable** as `aws:PrincipalAccount`. The avaiable IAM variables are listed in [Request information that you can use for policy variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-infotouse) .